# When i create usercreationform in django the username field is auto selected and how can i fix it

Tags: django

Greeting, I am new in django. Username is auto selected when i reload the page why is this and how can i fix it.

[image: See the image]

Answer (score 0):

Please share your forms.py file and try to change username field by label:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

class Meta():
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ('username','email','password1','password2')

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'User Name'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```